# vba - excel - if value = next row value then copy another value

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning guys,
I have a problem with the modify the data in a file.
I'd like my script take as a reference the data in column H and go to act only if the data is equal to the data of the next row, copying the values of the column I and J of the second line and pasting them in the first free cell after the column J in the top row.

Now the file is organized so
[image: Now the file is organized so]

I would like it to become so

[image: I would like it to become so]

the only code that I was able to write is this:

```
With ws1
For row = 2 To 1000

    If .Cells(8, row).Value Like .Cells(8, row + 1).Value Then

        .Cells(9 - 2, row).Value = .Cells(9, row + 1).Value

 End If
 Next
 End With
```

but obviously it is wrong and it does not minimally what I would ...

I'm really stuck .... help me please.

Comment: Where do you get 2012, 2013 and 2014 when column G only has 2015. Is there important data we are not seeing in those screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code has been tested and works on my sample data.

```
With ws1

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1

        If .Range("H" & i) = .Range("H" & i - 1) Then

            .Range(.Range("I" & i), .Range("I" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
                Destination:=.Range("H" & i - 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)

            .Range(.Range("I" & i), .Range("I" & i).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents

            'uncomment below line if you want to remove rows where data is copied up
            '.Range("H" & i).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next

End With
```

Comment: Very nice.  I didn't think about using a delete pattern but that looks good.  I would change `.Range("H" & i).EntireRow.Delete` to  `.Rows(i).delete` but that's just a pet peeve of mine.