# If Statement comparing strings in different rows but the same column

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm attempting to combine 2 rows on my excel spreadsheet into 1 row based on a particular condition being true.

I would like for my vba code to determine whether or not the string of characters in row 2 = the string of characters in row 3.

If they are equal, I would like to copy all of row 3 to column Q in row and then continue on comparing the string values of rows 3 and 4, 4 and 5, etc to the last used row of the spreadsheet.

I've attempted to modify code I've found on Stack Overflow but still can't get my macro to run.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to a similar situation I found in Stack Overflow while I was researching how to create my VBA code but I couldn't get the sample code to work for me.  Not sure why.  [vba - excel - if value = next row value then copy another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868115/vba-excel-if-value-next-row-value-then-copy-another-value?rq=1)

Here's part of the Excel worksheet I'm working with.  I did have to modify the information on the spreadsheet so that it wouldn't be too wide to paste.

[Member Data spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de2bq.png)

Comment: please share your code. Also, characters in row 2 any column? Copy to same current row?  You can possibly also just use a helper column, e.g. A1 = A2 and filter on the True result and copy.

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results (more than one match in the sample data please).  Additionally please provide any code you've tried so far.

Comment: With vba you can loop comparing with Offset(1,0) to  check against next cell below if in same column, and should terminate at last row - 1 to ensure you don't compare against the empty cell after the used range.

Comment: I've updated the post to include an image of my spreadsheet and how it needs to work.  I've also referenced a specific question and response in Stack Overflow that I was trying to modify for my particular situation but I couldn't get it to work for me.  Thanks so much for taking the time to try and help me out.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Wow!  This is definitely more than I could have generated on my own.  However, when I tried to run it with my test data, I got an error from Visual Basic saying subscript is Out of Range.  Can you explain what this error message means?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
 Public Sub ArrangeData()
    Dim i As Long, unionRng As Range, lastRow As Long, counter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")         'change as appropriate
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:G" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("G2:G" & lastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes ' 'Sort to ensure in order (and blanks will be at end

        For i = 3 To .Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
            If .Cells(i, "G") = .Cells(i - 1, "G") Then
                counter = counter + 1
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 6).Copy .Cells(i - counter, .Cells(i - counter, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1)
            Else
                counter = 0
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 3 To .Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "H")) Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Cells(i, "H"))
                Else
                    Set unionRng = .Cells(i, "H")
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: Did you try running this? You would need to change ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") to the sheet name of the sheet containing your data. Do you want anything explaining?

Comment: Any feedback on this please?

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Every time I trick to run the macro, the first line is highlighted in yellow.  Here's what I modified as you instructed.  Did I do this right?ThisWorkbook("Memberdata.xlsb").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Nope. Are you working with the same workbook as the code is in?

Comment: If you intend this to use sheet 1 in the same workbook as the code is in then you simply say Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Did that make sense? If not, can you pastebin https://pastebin.com/ more of your code?